# How to center two figures heighthwise

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have two figures A and B, and A is larger than B. What can I do so that the center of the two figures is at the same height ?

```
\begin{figure}[]
\begin{center}

\subcaptionbox{\label{sfig:texta}}{\includegraphics[width=1.0cm]{A}}
\subcaptionbox{\label{sfig:textb}}{\includegraphics[width=1.0cm]{B}}

\end{center}
\caption{...}  
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I updated my answer so now you don't have to correct the counter manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `minipage`s, the `subfigure` environment (from the `subcaption` package) and a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{1cm}p{1cm}@{}}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{1cm}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.0cm]{example-image-a}
  \end{minipage} &
  \begin{minipage}[c]{1cm}
  \includegraphics[width=1.0cm,height=4cm]{example-image-b}
  \end{minipage} \\
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{1cm}
  \subcaption{}
  \label{sfig:testa}
  \end{subfigure} &
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{1cm}
  \subcaption{}
  \label{sfig:testb}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{tabular}
\caption{...}  
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]